# How can I increase the number of peers in my routing table associated with a given infohash

Tags: bittorrent, dht

I'm working on a side project and trying to monitor peers on popular torrents, but I can't see how I can get a hold of the full dataset.

If the *theoretical* limit on routing table size is 1,280 `(from 160 buckets * bucket size k = 8)` then I'm never going to be able to hold the full number of peers on a popular torrent `(~9,000 on a current top-100 torrent)`

My concern with simulating multiple nodes is low efficiency due to overlapping values. I would assume that their bootstrapping paths being similar would result in similar routing tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong since it would violate reliability goals of the DHT, you would essentially be performing an attack on the keyspace region and other nodes may detect and blacklist you and it would also simply be bad-mannered.

If you want to monitor specific swarms don't collect data passively from the DHT.

- if the torrents have trackers, just contact them to get peer lists
- connect to the swarm and get peer lists via [PEX](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0011.html) which provides far more accurate information than the DHT
- if you really want to use the DHT perform active lookups (`get_peers`) at regular intervals